# $ operator not defined for this S4 class when using boxcox from MASS

Tags: r

I have used `lmer` from the `lmertest` package and when I checked for the mixed linear assuptions (the homogeneity of variance is violated) so I want to do a `boxcox` transformation. However, when I run the `boxcox` command from the `MASS` package I see the error message:

```
boxcox(Ana_AUDPC_LmerTest, lambda = c(-3,3))
```

> "Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class"

`Ana_AUDPC_LmerTest` is the object containing the `lmer` output.

Comment: From which package is `boxcox`? The simple answer is probably that this function just does not work with lme4 models.

Comment: it is from "MASS" package and i called for it

Comment: The documentation of `MASS::boxcox`clearly says "Currently only lm and aov objects are handled."

Comment: in principle you can use the `boxcoxmix` package for this (`optim.boxcoxmix()`), but I haven't been able to get it to work on a simple example ...